# Angular 1.2: Trigger page change from directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

I've recently come back to an angular project after some time away and I'm (once again) having some trouble making sense of the angular syntax.

**I'd just like to add a link to a button.**

Here's the code for the 'directionComponent' module, which is being added correctly, via eng-direction in the html.

```
var app = angular.module("directionComponent", []);    

app.directive('engDirection', function(completions) {
    return {        
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'components/direction.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.changePage = function (newPageID) {
                console.log("page should change to "+newPageID);
            }
        }

    };
});
```

The console.log message gets triggered as expected via ng-click but I have very little idea as to how to trigger a page change. Do I need to include $routeParams or $routeProvider somewhere?

I've searched but can't seem to find an answer that meshes with what I'm trying to do and I don't know what I need to change in the solutions I've found to make it work in my case.
If anyone has any pointers, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: which library are you using for routing: ui-router or ngRoute

Comment: We're using ngRoute.

Comment: so, do you want to change url?

Comment: use `$location.path('/new/path/url')` instead of console.log

Comment: Yes, I want to route to a different page; Effectively, add a link to the directionComponent button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to inject the `$location` service:

```
app.directive('engDirection', ['$location', function($location) { ... }]);
```

and then in your `function`:

```
scope.changePage = function (newPageID) {
    $location.path(newPageID);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Are you sure this syntax is correct? With my function content in place of your '...', I get an error saying a ']' is expected - but I've got one just before the final closing bracket. Is there a missing comma here maybe?

Comment: Yes indeed. It looks like a comma is needed between '$location' and function.

Comment: OK, that's working (!), but it looks like the format I'm passing the newPageID in is wrong. At the moment it's just the id of the page. I'm assuming it needs the full path. Will give that a go.

Answer (score 0):

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute']);
app.config(function($routeProvider)){
    $routeProvider
         .when('/test1', { templateUrl: 'test1.html', controller: 'MainCtrl'});
         .when('/test2', { templateUrl: 'test2.html', controller: 'MainCtrl'});
}
```

I suggest to use 'ngRoute' module to redirect to different page.
if your button redirect to **/test** than angular will request **test.html** and load that page into **ng-view**.  Also, you can specific which controller will be used with a template.

```
   div(class="container-fluid")
        div(ng-view)
            //Here, test.html will be loaded.
```

**UPDATE** 
For example, you have this HTML page.

*test1.html*

```
<div>
     <p>TEST1 {{ test }} </p>
</div>
```

*test2.html*

```
 <div>
     <p>TEST2 {{ test }} </p>
 </div>
```

*index.pug or index.jade or index.html*

```
doctype html
html
    head
        ...
    body(ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl as main")
        a(href="/test1") test1
        a(href="/test2") test2
        div(ng-view)
            //Here, test.html will be loaded.
```

So, if you start your web clinet with addess

> **http://localhost:3000/**

there will be no content at ng-view because you did not define **$routeProvider.when('/')** for root dir.
However, when you click *test1* link, angular will ask *test1.html* to server and load that page to under *ng-view*.

It will looks like this for

> http://localhost:3000/test1

```
doctype html
html
    head
        ...
    body(ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl as main")
        a(href="/test1") test1
        a(href="/test2") test2
        div(ng-view)
            <div>
                <p>TEST1 {{ test }} </p>
            </div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but there is not enough information here for me to make sense of the answer. I don't see anything that involves the directionComponent here. I'm assuming you must be referencing it obliquely somehow, but I don't see how.

Comment: @moosefetcher Sorry for not enough information. I will edit it will more information. I will edit now.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to update your answer. We already had ngRoute routing working in app.js - I just didn't know how to create a link from inside a directive in a different file; So I've marked the other answer as correct. Thanks again.